# Searching multiple SQL unique ID in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently trying to search multiple unique ID's from a database in C# . I am able to pull one using the following:

```
var atmtrans =
                    (from clf in db.CODE_LINE_FIELDS
                     where clf.FIELD2_DATA == "26"
```

I am still pretty new at C# and I assumed that I could do the following

`where clf.FIELD2_DATA == "26" + "20" + "27" + "64000"`

But then I realize that would basically be  `26202764000`

searching directly from the Database in SQL Management Studio would be as easy as the below:

```
 select * FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table] where Column in ('20',
  '26',
  '27',
  '64000')
```

Is it just as easy repeating the variable three different times with proper unique ID or is there another method?

Comment: researching the below methods, will respond once I look at the results.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for are simply multiple `OR` conditions:

```
where clf.FIELD2_DATA == "26" || clf.FIELD2_DATA== "20" || clf.FIELD2_DATA== "27" || clf.FIELD2_DATA== "64000"
```

---

**If you wanted a neater method**, you could create a `List<string>` of the IDs you're looking for and only select items within that list using `.Contains`.

```
List<string> ids = new List<string> { "26", "20", "27", "64000" };

var atmtrans = (from clf in db.CODE_LINE_FIELDS
                where ids.Contains(clf.FIELD2_DATA)
                ...
```

This is quite similar to a SQL `WHERE ... IN (...)`

Comment: +1 with the second, neater approach.  Mostly wanted to add for the OP: make sure your unique field has an index - and hopefully it's the primary/clustered index for the table.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating a function in C# that takes the ID you wish to search for.

```
searchforID(int ID){
 var data = from clf in db.CODE_LINE_FIELDSwhere clf.FIELD2_DATA = ID;
 return data
}
```

You could then call this multiple times.

Comment: This seems bad.  If you had 200 IDs, instead of letting the SQL engine process them in one transaction, you're creating 200 different transactions that have to all return individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
(from clf in db.CODE_LINE_FIELDS
                 where clf.FIELD2_DATA == "26" || 
                       clf.FIELD2_DATA == "20" || 
                       clf.FIELD2_DATA == "27" ||
                       clf.FIELD2_DATA == "64000"
```

This is specifying that you want to look for ID 26 or 20 or 27 or 64000

Comment: isn't ` || ` a or operator so that if it doesn't see ` 26 ` it will go to the next one correct? if I wanted it to search all of them would I switch it from ` || ` to ` | ` ?

Comment: @dwhilton The `or` is enacted upon *each record*, therefore the record will be included if its `FIELD2_DATA` property matches *any* of the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();            
            SqlCommand multikill= new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Table where ID='"+TextBox1.Text+"'", con);            
            if (int.Parse(multikill.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) > 1)
 {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table where ID='"+TextBox1.Text+"'",bag);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds,"Table");
                dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table"];
}
con.Close();
```

//I hope this is solving your problem

//And i hope i dont misunderstand

//Sorry i cant resist "MULTIKILL"